# On checking radio button, I want to get the datas in the particular div laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

Am doing purchasing and selling application.
In that I have multiple shipping address. When I selected a shipping address by checking and give checkout, I need to store those variables in a cart table.

How do I get the data of the checked div when i click checkout.
This is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    <!--Product -->
<div class="container">
  @if(Session::has('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-success" data-dismiss="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
      </div>
    @elseif(Session::has('danger'))
      <div class="alert alert-danger" data-dismiss="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{ Session::get('danger') }}
      </div>
    @endif
  <div class="row">
    <div> 
      <div class="bc-buy-item">
        <div class="bc-buy-accord">
          <div class="selected_address">
            <div class="form-group col-md-1"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="address" id="radio-center"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
              <span class="bc-prod-name">{{$user->name}}  {{$user->mobile}}</span>
              <span class="bc-number"> {{$user->address}}, {{$user->city}} - {{$user->pin}}, {{$user->state}}, {{$user->country}}.</span>
              <a href="/my-profile" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          @foreach($shippingAddress as $ship)
          <div class="selected_address">
            <div class="col-md-1 form-group"><input type="radio" name="address" id="radio-center"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
              <span class="bc-prod-name">{{$ship->name}}  {{$ship->mobile}}</span>
              <span class="bc-number"> {{$ship->shipping_address}}, {{$ship->shipping_city}} - {{$ship->shipping_pincode}}, {{$ship->shipping_state}}, {{$ship->shipping_country}}.</span>
              <a href="#editaddress" id="editaddr" 
              data-id="{{$ship->id}}" data-name="{{$ship->name}}" 
              data-address="{{$ship->shipping_address}}" data-city="{{$ship->shipping_city}}"
              data-pincode="{{$ship->shipping_pincode}}" data-state="{{$ship->shipping_state}}" 
              data-country="{{$ship->shipping_country}}" data-mobile="{{$ship->mobile}}"
              class="btn btn-default pull-right editadress" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>

        <div class="text-center"><a href="#address" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Shipping Address</a></div>
        <div class="bc-buy-accord">   
          <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Shipping</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                  
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media">
                              <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" width="100px" src="{{ asset($image) }}"> </a>                            
                              <div class="media-body product-cart-details">
                                <span class="bc-prod-name">{{$getProduct->name}} </span>
                                  <div class="bc-custom-prod">
                                      <span class="bc-number"> Seller Name : </span>
                                      <span class="bc-size-type">{{$seller->name}}</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="bc-custom-prod">
                                      <span class="bc-number"> Status : </span>
                                      <span class="bc-size-type">Leaves warehouse in {{$getProduct->shipping_within}} days</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div><a id="promocode" href="javascript:void(0)">Click here to apply for Promocode discount</a></div>
                                  <div id="promocode_value" style="display:none;">
                                    <form method="post" action="/promocode">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$getProduct->id}}"/>
                                      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                                          <input required data-error="Please enter the promocode" placeholder="Enter the promocode" class="form-control" name="promocode" type="text">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        <button class="pull-right">Submit</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </form>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center shipping"><strong>${{$getProduct->shipping_fee}}</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center price"><strong>${{$getProduct->price_per_unit}}</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><strong>${{$total_price}}</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><h3><strong>${{$total_price}}</strong></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>     </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" class="bc-btn bc-btn-save" onclick="location.href='/'">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
                        </button></td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" class="bc-btn bc-btn-remove" onclick="location.href='/payment'">
                            Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                        </button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="address" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter new shipping address</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('shippingaddress.store') }}" name="shippingaddress" id="shippingaddress" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="shipping-name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-mobile" class="control-label">Mobile:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="shipping-mobile"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-address" class="control-label">Address:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="shipping_address" id="shipping-address"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-city" class="control-label">City:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_city" id="shipping-city">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shpping-state" class="control-label">State:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_state" id="shpping-state">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-country" class="control-label">Country:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_country" id="shipping-country">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-pincode" class="control-label">Pin Code:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_pincode" id="shipping-pincode">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="editaddress" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit shipping address</h4>
      </div>
      <form method="put" class="form-horizontal" id="editshippingaddress" novalidate="novalidate" name="editpromocode">
      <div class="modal-body editAddressModal">
          <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id"/>
          <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="shipping-name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-mobile" class="control-label">Mobile:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="shipping-mobile"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-address" class="control-label">Address:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="shipping_address" id="shipping-address"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-city" class="control-label">City:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_city" id="shipping-city">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shpping-state" class="control-label">State:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_state" id="shpping-state">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-country" class="control-label">Country:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_country" id="shipping-country">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping-pincode" class="control-label">Pin Code:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_pincode" id="shipping-pincode">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#shippingaddress").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
        var myData = {
            user_id:$(this).find("[name='user_id']").val(),  
            name:$(this).find("[name='name']").val(),  
            mobile:$(this).find("[name='mobile']").val(),  
            shipping_address:$(this).find("[name='shipping_address']").val(),   
            shipping_city:$(this).find("[name='shipping_city']").val(),
            shipping_state:$(this).find("[name='shipping_state']").val(),
            shipping_country:$(this).find("[name='shipping_country']").val(),
            shipping_pincode:$(this).find("[name='shipping_pincode']").val(),
        }
     //   console.log(myData);
      $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: myData,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Shipping address added successfully");
                history.go(0);
            },
        });
    });

$('#promocode').click(function(){
    $('#promocode_value').slideToggle('slow');
});

$(document).on("click", ".editaddress", function () {
     var shippingId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".editAddressModal #shippingAddressId").val( shippingId );
});

$("body").on("click","#editaddr",function(){  
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var mobile = $(this).data('mobile');
    var address = $(this).data('address');
    var city = $(this).data('city');
    var state = $(this).data('state');
    var country = $(this).data('country');
    var pincode = $(this).data('pincode');

    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='id']").val(id);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='name']").val(name);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='mobile']").val(mobile);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("textarea[name='shipping_address']").val(address);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='shipping_city']").val(city);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='shipping_state']").val(state);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='shipping_country']").val(country);
    $(".editAddressModal").find("input[name='shipping_pincode']").val(pincode);
});

$("#editshippingaddress").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var id = $(this).find("[name='id']").val();
    var url = 'http://192.168.10.10/api/v1/shippingaddress/'+id;
    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    var myData = { 
        user_id:$(this).find("[name='user_id']").val(),  
        name:$(this).find("[name='name']").val(),  
        mobile:$(this).find("[name='mobile']").val(),  
        shipping_address:$(this).find("[name='shipping_address']").val(),   
        shipping_city:$(this).find("[name='shipping_city']").val(),
        shipping_state:$(this).find("[name='shipping_state']").val(),
        shipping_country:$(this).find("[name='shipping_country']").val(),
        shipping_pincode:$(this).find("[name='shipping_pincode']").val(),
    }
    console.log("data", myData);
 $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: myData,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
             alert("Shipping Address Updated Succesfully");
             history.go(0);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        }
    });
});
$("input[name='address']").change(function(){

});
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Try to make small fiddle to your problem rather than all code ?

Comment: It is laravel syntax. How do I install laravel in fiddle. My problem is simple. On clicking the checkbox I want to get the details of checked div